# Set and use variables outside timeline in javafx 8

Tags: java, javafx-8

I am trying to writing a javafx app to watch the system clipboard:

```
package sample;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.input.Clipboard;
import javafx.scene.input.ClipboardContent;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        primaryStage.show();

        final Clipboard clipboard = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard();
        final String oldString = "";
        final String newString = "";
        Timeline repeatTask = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(200), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                if (clipboard.hasString()) {
                    newString = clipboard.getString();
                    if(oldString != newString) {
                        System.out.printf("String changed in clipboard: " + newString);
                        oldString = newString;
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("String not changed.");
                    }
                }
            }
        }));
        repeatTask.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        repeatTask.play();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The problem is I need to store the old content of the clipboard outside the timeline object, and I need to make changes to them, but once they set as final -- as java requires -- modification is no longer possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have `oldString` as a field of your Application class:

```
private String oldString = "";

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    primaryStage.show();

    final Clipboard clipboard = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard();
    Timeline repeatTask = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(200), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            if (clipboard.hasString()) {
                String newString = clipboard.getString();
                if(!oldString.equals(newString)) {
                    System.out.printf("String changed in clipboard: " + newString);
                    oldString = newString;
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("String not changed.");
                }
            }
        }
    }));
    repeatTask.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    repeatTask.play();
}
```

This works because when you access `oldString`, you are actually accessing `this.oldString`, where `this` is final.

Also note that to compare strings, you should use `oldString.equals(newString)` instead of comparing object identities (`==`/`!=`).

Also, if you are using Java 8, you can get rid of the Timeline boilerplate using ReactFX:

```
private String oldString = "";

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    primaryStage.show();

    final Clipboard clipboard = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard();
    EventStreams.ticks(Duration.ofMillis(200)).subscribe(tick -> {
        if (clipboard.hasString()) {
            String newString = clipboard.getString();
            if(!oldString.equals(newString)) {
                System.out.printf("String changed in clipboard: " + newString);
                oldString = newString;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("String not changed.");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

For more information about using the timer from ReactFX, see my blog post http://tomasmikula.github.io/blog/2014/06/04/timers-in-javafx-and-reactfx.html

Comment: Awesome answer. I wish I could upvote 10 times! About ReactFX, I need to copy the ReactFX external library, right?

Comment: Could you please also have look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098813/listening-on-systesm-clipboard-using-javafx

Comment: Yes, ReactFX is an external library. You can either [download the ReactFX jar](https://github.com/TomasMikula/ReactFX/releases) manually and place it on your classpath, or, if you use a build system such as Maven or Gradle, you can add ReactFX as a dependency (see [ReactFX Maven coordinates](https://github.com/TomasMikula/ReactFX#maven-coordinates)) and have it downloaded automatically.