# Listening on system clipboard using JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, clipboard, javafx-8

As stated in the answer to this question, one can setup a Timeline to check whether there is a change in the system clipboard:

[Set and use variables outside timeline in javafx 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25082220/set-and-use-variables-outside-timeline-in-javafx-8)

But is there a better way? For example, an event listener? I have searched JavaFx 8 doc and didn't find anything obviously helpful.

Solutions using JavaFx is preferred, but all answers are welcome.

Answer (score 7):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.Clipboard;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        final Clipboard systemClipboard = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard();

        new com.sun.glass.ui.ClipboardAssistance(com.sun.glass.ui.Clipboard.SYSTEM) {
            @Override
            public void contentChanged() {
                System.out.print("System clipboard content changed: ");
                if ( systemClipboard.hasImage() ) {
                    System.out.println("image");
                } else if ( systemClipboard.hasString() ) {
                    System.out.println("string");
                } else if ( systemClipboard.hasFiles() ) {
                    System.out.println("files");
                }
            }
        };

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane()));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

Test:

- Press key Print Screen
- Ctrl+C for selected string
- Ctrl+c for selected files

Comment: how daring to access internal api :) +1

Comment: This doesn't work for me on macOS 10.12.6 and Java 8 update 171.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't a better way. There are no events sent round when the clipboard contents change (especially if it's from outside of the Java application) and so only a polling approach is appropriate.